# Excluding a directory in for loop's search

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following line of code:

```
FOR /R D:\1_FOLDER %f IN (*.jpg,*.png) DO XCOPY %f D:\2_FOLDER /H /C
```

The first problem what i have, the command doesn't run, i get the error

> Invalid numbers of parametres

The second problem in directory 1_FOLDER i have 2 more folders  X_FOLDER and Y_FOLDER, i want the for loop to search only in X_FOLDER, and copy only files of the X_FOLDER.

I have the second problem same when i want to copy from C:\ , i want to exclude the Windows folder from for loop's search.

Comment: I am sure the error message results from files/folders with spaces in their paths, so `xcopy` receives more than two parameters; to overcome this, put all paths in between `""`: `FOR /R "D:\1_FOLDER" %f IN (*.jpg,*.png) DO XCOPY "%~f" "D:\2_FOLDER" /H /C`; for excluding specific folders, I see two options: 1) use the `/EXCLUDE` option of `xcopy`, or 2) use `if` to filter out certain locations...

Comment: I tried your option and now working but now have a new little problem, in 1_FOLDER i have 3 folders, one is hidden folder, one is system folder and one is hidden and system folder and the for loop doesn't copied the file of hidden folder. And if you can, can you explain me what mean "%~f", i don't know what mean "~" symbol. And /EXCLUDE option is working and for directories?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with hidden folders, `for /R` seems to skip hidden *files*, but not hidden *folders*; anyway, you could omit the `for /R` loop at all and provide a command line like this for every file pattern: `xcopy /C /H /K /S /E /I /EXCLUDE:excludefile.txt "D:\1_FOLDER\*.jpg" "D:\2_FOLDER"`. About the `~` symbol in `%~f`: it removes potential surrounding `""` from the returned string; see `for /?` for details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message comes from `xcopy` when you specify unquoted paths containing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters (or other token separators like `,`, `;`, `=`, <kbd>TAB</kbd> or non-break spaces (ASCII `0xFF`)).

Anyway, actually I do not see any reason to use a `for /R` loop for the task at hand, because `xcopy` features an `/EXCLUDE` option. Here is an excerpt of the help test appearing when typing `xcopy /?`:

> ```
>   /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
>                Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
>                should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
>                strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
>                copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
>                example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
>                all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
>                .obj extension respectively.
> ```

So for your example, create a text file (let us call it `exclusions.lst`) with the following content:

```
D:\1_FOLDER\Y_FOLDER\
```

Alternatively, if you want *every* subdirectory called `Y_FOLDER` in any location to be excluded, write:

```
\Y_FOLDER\
```

Since you have multiple file patterns (`*.jpg` and `*.png`) to be processed, you could provide an `xcopy` command line for each of them (let `xcopy` do the recursion by using the appropriate switches, rather than wrapping a `for /R` loop around):

```
xcopy /C /H /K /S /I /EXCLUDE:exclusions.lst "D:\1_FOLDER\*.jpg" "D:\2_FOLDER"
xcopy /C /H /K /S /I /EXCLUDE:exclusions.lst "D:\1_FOLDER\*.png" "D:\2_FOLDER"
```

Or you could list the file patterns in another text file (let us call it `patterns.lst`):

```
*.jpg
*.png
```

Then you could use a `for /F` loop to read that file and feed each pattern/line to an `xcopy` command:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%P in (patterns.lst) do (
    xcopy /C /H /K /S /I /EXCLUDE:exclusions.lst "D:\1_FOLDER\%%~nxP" "D:\2_FOLDER"
)
```

Do not forget to replace each `%%` by `%` if you want to try this in command prompt (`cmd`) directly.

Both text files `exclusions.lst` and `patterns.lst` are expected to be in the current working directory.

Note that all methods shown here do not copy any empty directories from the source.

If you need advanced options for specifying filters to exclude or include certain files, you might be interested in the [`robocopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Comment: I don't know If i understand fine, so i can using xcopy command without "for" for same task, in my case? And what mean "eol=| delims="?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant! I just [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39479650/2) my answer and removed the `/E` switch from `xcopy` to avoid orphaned empty directories in the target. Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text; you will find an `/F` option of `for` to read from text files; the option string `"eol=| delims="` defines the way the read text file is parsed/tokenised; here I want to read every line completely, so I defined to use no delimiter (`delims=`) and I changed the ignore character to an unused one (`eol=|`)...