# Copy all files of a type from all my computer exclude some directories

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file who is doing the following things, search all file of a type from all my computer, but exclude some directories from searching, like Windows or Program Files and copy only files în one folder, without the parent/parents directory/directories.

I tried in 3 ways:

First with ROBOCOPY command

```
ROBOCOPY C:\ %location% *.jpg *.png /S /XD "Windows" "Program Files" /XJ /W:0 / R:0
```

It's working perfect but i don't need the parents directory of the files, i want all files who was find to copy în one folder.

Second way was with XCOPY

```
XCOPY /C /H /S /EXCLUDE: excludefiles.txt "%source%" "%destination%"
```

But the same problem, copy files with their parents directories.

And third way with For Loop, where i used same xcopy.

```
FOR "eol=| delims=" %%f IN (*.jpg,*.png) DO ( XCOPY /C /H /S /EXCLUDE:excludefiles.txt "%source%\%%~nxf" "%destination%"
```

But same problem, i tried in for loop and with copy, but copy doesn't have options to search in subdirectories, what for me it's also a problem.

So if you can help me with this problem I will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around a bit and came up with the following script (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SOURCE=D:\"          & rem // (root directory of source location)
set "TARGET=H:\copydata\" & rem // (target location)
set PATTERNS="*.jpg","*.png"               & rem // (list of file patterns)
set EXCLUSIONS="D:\dontcopy\","\ignoreit\" & rem // (list of exclusions)
set "EXCLFILE=exclusions.lst" & rem /* (name of temporary exclusions file;
                                rem     this must not contain spaces!) */
set "EXCLFDIR=%~dp0" & rem /* (location of temporary exclusions file;
                       rem     `%~dp0` is the parent dir. of this script) */

rem // Create temporary exclusions file:
cd /D "%EXCLFDIR%"
if defined EXCLUSIONS (
    > "%EXCLFILE%" (
        for %%E in (%EXCLUSIONS%) do (
            echo(%%~E
        )
    )
    rem // Build exclusions option for `xcopy`:
    set "EXCLUSIONS=/EXCLUDE:%EXCLFILE%"
)

rem /* Create target directory to ensure it exists
rem    (if the target does not exist, `xcopy` prompts for
rem     whether it is a File or a Directory; if it exists,
rem     no prompt appears; `2> nul` surpresses error message
rem     of `md` in case the target already exists): */
2> nul md "%TARGET%"
rem // Enumerate all files in source recursively:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    cd /D "%SOURCE%" ^& dir /B /S /A:-D %PATTERNS%
') do (
    rem // Do the actual flat copying here:
    (
        rem /* Surpress output (also `1 File(s)`) by `> nul`
        rem    (`xcopy` outputs the copied file plus the summary
        rem     `1 File(s)`; to avoid that summary after each file,
        rem     the entire output of `xcopy` is surpressed): */
        > nul xcopy /L /Y /C /H /K %EXCLUSIONS% "%%~F" "%TARGET%"
        rem /* (after testing, remove `/L` to do actual copying) */
    ) && (
        rem /* Return every copied file to see what has been copied;
        rem    `&&` lets `echo` execute inly if `xcopy` succeeded: */
        echo(%%~F
    )
)

rem // Delete temporary exclusions file:
del "%EXCLFILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

You do not need to create an exclusions file for `xcopy` (as in your similar [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39474291)), because that file is created automatically by the script, temporarily. You simply need to define all the file and directory locations, file patterns and exclusions in the section with the `Define constants here:` remark.

After having tested whether the output lists all files you want to copy, **you need to remove the `/L` switch from the `xcopy` command** in order to actually copy and files.

Comment: I'm begginer in batch scripting, I started to scripting in batch a week ago, but after more previews i understand the script without three line of code `2> nul md "%targer%"` , `>nul xcopy... ` and why `echo(%%~F`

Comment: And line `set "EXCLFDIR=%~dp0"` i don't understand what is the container of script.

Comment: See my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39497872/2) where I extended the explanatory remarks... concerning `%~dp0`: type `call /?` in a command prompt window; you will find that `%0` points to the batch file itself, `%~dp0` points to its parent directory; see also [this resource](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Comment: I tried your script, it isn't working, it echo all files and later doesn't copy anything.

Comment: As soon as you tested the script (without the `/L` switch) please let me know whether it worked...

Comment: It working perfectly, thank you for your help and your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the last command with a minor change:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /s/b *.jpg,*.png') DO ( XCOPY /H /S  "%%~f" "%destination%")
```

This will loop over all files listed by `dir /s/b *.jpg,*.png` there are additional attributes for hidden / system files etc.

Then it simply copies everything into the flat destination folder. Note: the destination folder must end in a `\`

----- edit - repeating for another partition ------

```
    set destination=c:\temp\batches\dir3\

    FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /s/b c:\*.jpg') DO call :copyWithExcludes %%f
    FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /s/b d:\*.png') DO call :copyWithExcludes %%f

    pause
    goto:eof

    :copyWithExcludes
    XCOPY /H /S /Y  "%~1" "%destination%"
    goto:eof
```

Comment: I don't understand your question? What about a partition?

Comment: If i want all files of C:\ or D:\ , and one more thing, the dir will execut one time, so if i have destination in source directory the files will not copy and copy over and over again?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi, you could append the trailing backslash to `"%destination%\"`; this ensures there is one (it does not harm even if the variable already contains one). `dir /S /B` does not return hidden (and system?) files per default, unless you specify `/A`; writing `/A:-D` was even better, as this excludes directories...

Comment: I've modified my post with the approach I'd take to using 2 partitions. Add your Destination directory into the exclusion list to prevent it giving you the cyclic error (although you can just ignore this).

Comment: @Xtx, `xcopy` prompts for overwrite per default; add the `/Y` switch to overwrite files already present in the destination without asking...

Comment: OK, i tried your example, but is a huge problem, no one file from a source who have in name spaces, like E:\Example_folder\Folder 1\...*.jpg, it copy only file who doesn't have spaces in path's name, like E:\Example_folder\Folder_1\...*.jpg

Comment: Replace "delims=" with "tokens=*" and try again.